# Firebase: Can't access css and js files while hosting a website on Firebase. Get this error: GET net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-hosting

I was trying to host an existed project on Firebase which already have a css and js file. But it didn't seem to include my css and js files into the website.
I followed all of these steps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meofoNuK3vo&index=21&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmnJ_FpMOZgyg6XcIGBu2OX

The project directory now looks like this:
\public (folder) (containing: index.html 404.html)

\css (folder) (containing: style.css)

\js (folder) (containing: index.js)

firebase.json

.firebaserc

Here is the website: https://together-cb.firebaseapp.com/

The index file looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

    <script src="/__/firebase/4.8.0/firebase.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-view">
    ....
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but you're mixing up the forms of script includes.  You either use the "/__/..." form of includes when using Firebase Hosting, *or* you use the gstatic URLs (required when not using Hosting).  Not both.  See the docs for clarification.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: Also, what are you expecting to happen when you include `../js/index.js` from a top-level index.html?  Where does .. go in this case?

Comment: I fxied the forms of script includes. I didn't help.
For your question: I guessed it'd go from the "public"(where the index.html is in) back to the parent folder (which I named "together"). Then from there it could go to either "js" folder or "css" folder wherever I want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I added this line below my body tag and it solved.

```
<script src="/__/firebase/6.1.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

also, you can see the instruction here 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 0):

Make soure that all your assets(css,js,img) and html are in /public